# ERROR 403 (FORBIDDEN) :Your client does not have permission to get URL

Tags: json, xml, rest

I want to get the web search results in XML or JSON format, so I'm trying Custom Search Engine to do this using REST API, but when put any URL with different parameters like cx, API key, query, scope. I get always the same error:

> Your client does not have permission to get URL /search?q=socer&hl=en&start=10&num=10&output=xml&client=950599431012-4mdbg8eqvb30cf6hamamq8sfihn71qku.apps.googleusercontent.com&cx=006664130785464139277:u_p0bwcuncc from this server. (Client IP address: 105.190.4.82)

If there are other solution for my problem please show it to me.

Comment: Are you using this on chrome? It is possible You could have a type of malware. users facing this issue usually found out the reason behind it was a "proxy server malware".

Comment: Are you using any VPN?

Comment: I got the same error when trying to install Firebase AppTester

Answer (score 15):

Because 'Firebase' sanctioned some country like(Iran) this error responds to users.

Comment: then what to do now??

Comment: Using a VPN, I still get the same error :-/

Answer (score 8):

I had this error when clicking on the Trigger URL of a Google Cloud Function, this answer on Server Fault fixed the [Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME from this server cloud function](https://serverfault.com/a/1010147/607547).

It says that you need to:

> manually add the Cloud Functions Invoker permission to the allUsers
> user in the Cloud Functions page in the Google Cloud Console.

Perhaps you also can change roles and permissions in your case to get it running?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like your IP is blocked by Google.

Using `vpn` or a `proxy` should solve the problem.

Comment: Using a VPN, I still get the same error :-/

Comment: Adding to Tina's comment, I only get this using VPN in certain regions.

Answer (score 2):

I started in this thread, but in my case, I discovered the client was attempting to use ipv6.  I confirmed this by trying wget instead and the error messages hinted at some ipv6 addresses along with the same 403 error.  So I assumed maybe curl was attempting the same.

**With curl**

```
curl -sL https://golang.org/dl/go1.20.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/dl/go1.20.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

**With wget**

```
wget https://golang.org/dl/go1.20.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
--2023-10-05 19:03:18--  https://golang.org/dl/go1.20.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
Resolving golang.org (golang.org)... 2a00:1450:4003:802::2011, 172.217.17.17
Connecting to golang.org (golang.org)|2a00:1450:4003:802::2011|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2023-10-05 19:03:19 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Looking up the method to force --ipv4 fixed the fetch for me.  In my case it was an ansible script trying to download and install go on a remote server.

```
curl -sL --ipv4 https://golang.org/dl/go1.20.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Underrated solution! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a vpn extension turned on by mistake in Google Chrome.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me. I think cause was during execution of `firebase deploy` command I closed the terminal and command couldn't be completed. Probably firebase adjusts permissions during deploy command function creation and when command breaks permissions could not be executed.

So you can try to delete the function and deploy it again.

Comment: this helped me. My `firebase deploy` had error 1st time. It did succeed on 2nd time but then I start to have this forbidden error. I deleted the functions, renamed the function and deployed again and it worked again.

Answer (score -1):

Well it's a hit-or-miss situation. Many users have faced this type of issue.
Please try a few solutions from below:

1. Clearing your browser history.
2. Try using a tool for cleaning up malwares.