# extract the number of results from google search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a web scraper to extract the number of results of searching in a google search which appears on the top left of the page of search results. I have written the code below but I do not understand why phrase_extract is None. I want to extract the phrase "About 12,010,000,000 results". which part I am making a mistake? may be parsing the HTML incorrectly?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def pyGoogleSearch(word):   
    address='http://www.google.com/#q='
    newword=address+word
    #webbrowser.open(newword)
    page=requests.get(newword)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    phrase_extract=soup.find(id="resultStats")
    print(phrase_extract)

pyGoogleSearch('world')
```

[image: example]

Comment: instead of scraping you should consider using their [API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/)

Comment: That is not free over a certain amount. But Do you know why the result of API is different with this method?

Comment: API is a more promising way than scraping. the site owner doesn't bide to inform you about changes and hence your code might become nonfunctional at a certain time. However, API is well developed and maintained and the response time is much quicker compared to scraping.

Comment: @Gahan so that is the reason that when I scrape with beautiful soup I get different results in comparison to searching in google and alos api? It means I get three different results by these three different methods

Comment: surely, because you scrape the data with id or class of tag and they might change it or nest among another tag. it's just html structure. whereas you have a documentation of APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually using the wrong url to query google's search engine. You should be using `http://www.google.com/search?q=<query>`.

So it'd look like this:

```
def pyGoogleSearch(word):
    address = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='
    newword = address + word
    page = requests.get(newword)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    phrase_extract = soup.find(id="resultStats")
    print(phrase_extract)
```

You also probably just want the text of that element, not the element itself, so you can do something like

```
phrase_text = phrase_extract.text
```

or to get the actual value as an integer:

```
val = int(phrase_extract.text.split(' ')[1].replace(',',''))
```

Comment: thank you! it works! but here is two problems. first, when I print  phrase_extract it shows me this: <div class="sd" id="resultStats">About 515,000,000 results</div> while the class is not "sd". The second problem is that the result 515,000,000 is different with the number I see when I search in google.

Comment: I edited my question with the entire image of xml code below the window.  The picture appeared in "entire image description here" in my question.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea how to extract the exact number of 515,000,000 from the text? I use  text.split but it gives me this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,170,000,000'

Comment: @RoseA I've added a snippet for grabbing the integer value

Comment: thank you and if you know the answer of my other questions I would be grateful if you could adress them

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to see what output would be from `div` above. Sometimes it will show the output.

Also, make sure you're using `user-agent` since Google could treat your script as a tablet `user-agent` (of something different) with different `.class`, `#id` tags, and so on. This could be the reason why your output is empty `[]`.

Here's the code and [replit.com](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Number-of-Search-results-python-bs4#main.py) to see the number of *search results*:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=beautiful+cookies',
                        headers=headers,
                        stream=True)

response.raw.decode_content = True

tree = html.parse(response.raw)

# lxml is used to select element by XPath
# Requests + lxml: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466033/1291371
# note: you can achieve it easily with bs4 as well by grabbing "#result-stats" id selector.
result = tree.xpath('//*[@id="result-stats"]/text()')[0]

print(result)

# About 3,890,000,000 results
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi to achieve the same but in more easy fashion.

Part of JSON:

```
"search_information": {
 "organic_results_state":"Results for exact spelling",
 "total_results": 3890000000,
 "time_taken_displayed": 0.65,
 "query_displayed": "beautiful cookies"
}
```

Code to integrate:

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "beautiful cookies",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

result = results["search_information"]['total_results']
print(result)

# 4210000000
```

> Discrailmer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using just command line, try filtering with [`htmlq`](https://github.com/mgdm/htmlq):

```sh
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
term="something"

curl --silent  -A "$user_agent" "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=$term" | htmlq "#result-stats" | grep -o "About.*results" | grep -o '[0-9]' | tr -d "\n"
```

You could try other user agents to avoid [this 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612781/error-403-forbidden-your-client-does-not-have-permission-to-get-url).

There are better ways (probably with `awk` or `sed`) instead of `grep` and `td`.