# Getting the number of results of a google search using python in 2020?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-search

There were solutions provided before, but they don't work anymore :

[extract the number of results from google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177265/extract-the-number-of-results-from-google-search)

for example the above code doesn't work anymore because the number of results doesn't seem to even be in the respond, there is no resultStats ID, in my browser the result is in the id of "result-status" but this doesn't exist in the respond

I don't want to actually use the API of google because there is a big limit on daily search, and i need to search for thousands of words daily, what is the solution for me?

Comment: That div is probably populated by JS, so you could use something like selenium. I believe doing so would be against their ToS

Comment: @rdas i need to find the number of hits for a list of words like 100 word, many times a day, and right now i do it manually, whats the difference for them if i do it manually or via code, the load on their server will still be the same if not less! how can i use selenium to resolve this i have never used it before

Comment: You'll have to ask google why they prohibit automated access - but it's their site & they can do that if they please. Regarding selenium I would suggest going through some basic tutorials & check answers such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python

Comment: @rdas i looked at some tutorials for this, but it seems to not be really scalable if i want to for example search one thousand word and find the number of results, is there any faster way?