# Your client does not have permission to get URL after deploying express API app on firebase hosting/functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I've created an Express API app. I want it to be served on firebase. I'm refering to [this](https://medium.com/boca-code/the-basic-process-is-that-we-will-use-firebase-cloud-functions-to-create-a-single-function-app-13ba3b852077) tutorial. As I understood this tutorial, it created new project for firebase and started writing APIs in it's `index.js`. But I wanted to point every API request to the APIs I created so I did a change in `index.js` of funtions folder

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const app = require("../app");       //this is app.js of my express API app

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I tried this on local with command `firebase emulators:start`. It is working fine on local but not working when deploying it on firebase.

Below is my folder structure

[image: this is my folder structure]

I'm getting

```
Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/app/users/delete?id=1</code> from this server.</h2>
```

I searched this on SO and found few solutions like
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612781/error-403-forbidden-your-client-does-not-have-permission-to-get-url).

As I am new to express and firebase both. Any help is appriciated to resolve this issue.

Thanks