Response from Google Play Developer API: Your client does not have permission to get URL
When I call the following from a terminal on my server based using the Google Play Developer API:
curl "https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.example.myapp/purchases/products/inapp_product/tokens/[redacted]?access_token=[redacted]"
I get a valid response:
{
  "purchaseTimeMillis": "1654174963106",
  "purchaseState": 0,
  "consumptionState": 0,
  "developerPayload": "",
  "orderId": "GPA.1234-0101-3444-54321",
  "acknowledgementState": 1,
  "kind": "androidpublisher#productPurchase",
  "regionCode": "CH"
}

Same when entering the URL directly into a browser.
But calling the same command from within a Docker container hosted on the same server as above, or sending a request to this URL via a node app hosted in the Docker container, I get the following response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.example.myapp/purchases/products/inapp_product/tokens/[redacted]</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

Sometimes I will get valid responses for several days, and then suddenly it will start returning errors like that shown above… despite using the same auth methods from the same Docker container on the same host.
Any idea what the issue is?  It's the same public IP both on the server and from a Docker container on the server, so I doubt it's Google blocking requests based on IP address because it would be blocked when the request is sent direct from the host terminal and also from within a container running on the host?  Perhaps some form of rate limiting is being applied?  But the daily quota is very high and I'm nowhere near exceeding that.
I wish that the error message were more informative... how can I "not have permission" when sending a request to the URL in one place, but have permission for the same URL (sending the same credentials) in another place?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77239957/549372

@MartinZeitler thanks for the suggestion but forcing IPv4 doesn't make any difference... it is already using IPv4 it seems. And the node app where this is running does work for a few days, and then gives this error, without any reason to switch from v4 to v6. I feel like maybe it's Google applying a block or rate limit but I wish that the error message was more informative.
